# SQL trigger failes with post_content

Tags: posts, database, mysql, post-content

Let me tell you my story... I was having an issue with **Â** char visible within the post's content. Instead of editing each one, I was passing a simple query:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE( post_content, binary 'Â', '' );
```

Everything was fine so far, however, after adding new posts the issue was back again, so I thought trigger would be the key! So I've written one as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER watch_posts 
  AFTER INSERT ON wp_posts 
  FOR EACH ROW 
  UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE( post_content, binary 'Â', '' );
```

From this point within most of the posts I'm having now **blank edit page** where word count is equal to 0. But the database still consist of post_content which is not empty. How to prevent existing posts to not be blank anymore?

Comment: First I'd remove that trigger. Next I'd disable all plugins, check to see if the Â problem is gone (by adding a new test post, if necessary). If it's gone, re-enable plugins one by one till you find the problem. If it's not a plugin, try switching to a default theme (eg, Twenty Sixteen) and see if the problem is cured or if it persists.

Comment: and if the problem remains after all the tests that @PatJ speaks about, it may be better to clean this caracter with a plugin instead of editing the database

Comment: Looks like you are using the wrong charset on some of your DB tables.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a filter for you. It will filter the character before the post get saved in the database and it's using the **WordPress** way. If you use this I think you're not gonna be needed the trigger. Here it is-

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'the_dramatist_filter_content_before_insert' , '99', 2 );

function the_dramatist_filter_content_before_insert( $data , $postarr ) {

    $search  = array('Â'); // You can add other replacement finding here also
    $replace = array(''); // The replacements

    $data['post_content'] = str_replace($search, $replace, $data['post_content']);

    // Now just return the data
    return $data;
}
```

Hope that thing helps.